# c# FileSystemWatcher fires on multiple clients

Tags: c#, filesystemwatcher

I'm using a `FileSystemWatcher` to watch a directory. I created a `_Created()` event handler to fire when a file is moved to this folder. My problem is the following:

The files in this directory get created when the user hits a "real life button" (a button in our stock, not in the application). The `FileSystemWatcher` take this file, do some stuff in the system and then delete it. That wouldn't be a problem when the application runs only once. But it is used by 6 clients. So every application on every client is trying to delete it. If one client is too slow, it will throw an exception because the file is already deleted.

What I'm asking for is: Is there a way to avoid this?

I tried using loops and check if the file still exists, but without any success.

```
while (File.Exists(file))
{
    File.Delete(file);
    Thread.Sleep(100);
}
```

Can someone give me a hint how it could probably work?

Comment: according to the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.delete%28v=vs.110%29.aspx): *If the file to be deleted does not exist, no exception is thrown.*

Comment: Typical race condition, eh? Should multiple applications be able to handle a file at the same time, failing gracefully when the rug is pulled from under them, or is only one allowed to handle it at a given time?

Comment: Whether the 6 clients are accessing a network share or there are 6 instances of the process, you will need to implement some kind of concurrency control. Having something that inserts the data into a database for access by the clients is one way.

Comment: Hmm okay, but it does throw one. Or maybe I'm just interpreting it wrong. It throws a `System.UnauthorizedAccessException`. `Access to the path is denied.` But it must have something to do with the watcher, because its only thrown by those clients who are too slow to delete and only when a new file goes into the folder.

Comment: You seem to be relying on the delete as a mechanic to control access to the file by multiple "things", you cannot do that/make that assumption.

Comment: Is the file an executable that might be in use? the documentation link provided by Default shows what could cause this error, do any of those apply?

Comment: @Sayse The file is a .txt file. It gets deleted very fast (under 1 sec) because the system just read it and then it doesn't need the file anymore.

Comment: @Alex K. Hmm okay... Sounds not very well :/ Do you have an idea/a hint how I could do it?

Comment: Multiple instances are reacting to the file, processing it and then they all try to delete it, right? What if one instance is able to process and delete it before another instance even gets the chance to read it? How do you want the system to behave?

Comment: Do you mean that you run 6 of same applications at the same time?Or 1 server and 6 client?

Comment: @PieterWitvoet That could be a solution but what if the machine which is able to process and delete the file is not online?

Comment: @AngusChung It's not on 1 server, it's on every client and there is no need of a server. But some users and our stock employees use it at the same time.

Comment: @Tyler: I didn't offer a solution, I mentioned an edge case ('what if instance A processes and deletes the file before instance B is able to read it') and wondered what you want your system to do in that case. Is it OK if one instance handles the file, telling the others 'don't touch this, I'm handling this one' or should all instances try to handle it? Should the file be removed after one instance has processed it or only after all instances have done so?

Comment: @PieterWitvoet Yes, this is okay. The file has to be removed when one watcher is finished, not all. Which watcher it is doesn't matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Design**

If you want a file to be processed by a single instance only (for example, the first instance that reacts gets the job), then you should implement a locking mechanism. Only the instance that is able to obtain a lock on the file is allowed to process and remove it, all other instances should skip the file.

If you're fine with all instances processing the file, and only care that at least one of them succeeds, then you need to figure out which exceptions indicate a genuine failure and which ones indicate a failure caused by the actions of another instance.

**Locking**

To 'lock' a file, you can open it with share-mode `FileShare.None`. This prevents other processes from opening it until you close the file. However, you'll then need to close the file before you can delete it, which leaves a small gap during which another instance could open the file.

A better solution is to create a separate lock file for that purpose. Create it with file-mode `FileMode.Create` and share-mode `FileShare.None` and keep it open until the whole process is finished, including the removal of the processed file. Then the lock file can be closed and optionally removed.

**Exception**

As for the `UnauthorizedAccessException` you got, according to the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.delete%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), that means one of 4 things:

1. You don't have the required permission
2. The file is an executable file that is in use
3. The path is a directory
4. The file is read-only

1 and 4 seem most likely in this case (if the file was open in another process you'd get an `IOException`).

Comment: Thank you, I'll do it in this way

Answer (score 0):

If you want to synchronize access between multiple clients on the same computer you should use a [Named Mutex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.mutex%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).